# How to run the hadoop simple program through command line

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to the hadoop technologies .How to run the simple program through command line.I'm using windows environment.I install the Cygwin.Can you help me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below URLs.

http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html

http://hayesdavis.net/2008/06/14/running-hadoop-on-windows/

If you are new to Hadoop, try using one of the IDE plugins. This will help you get started quickly.

http://karmasphere.com/Studio-Eclipse/quick-click-guide.html

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipsePlugIn

FYI ..... Hadoop on Windows is not recommended for Production.

Comment: I use the above three link but i didn't get.First link every thing is fine when i open perspective it selecting the Map/Reduce and displaying below but click function is not working .It  means i click  the New Hadoop location it's not opening the popup window.Can any one help me...

Answer (score 0):

Are your program written in Java? If so, you need to compile your program and pack the compiled files into a Jar file. And then run the program with hadoop command:

```
${hadoop_home}/bin/hadoop jar ${your_program_jar_file} ${main_class_of_jar}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Hadoop commands from anywhere in the terminal/command line, but only if the `$path` variable is set properly.

The syntax would be like this:

```
hadoop fs -<command> or hdfs fs -<command>
```

You review [the docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/hdfs_shell.html) for more information.